# Laravel 4.x, routing multiple related parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

With a link like

```
http://example.com/catalog/slug/brand/product
```

and a route like

```
Route::get('catalog/{slug}/{brand}/{product}', 'Controller@method');
```

and knowing that each parameter has a bind which check if the parameter exists or not.

And I have 3 tables:

```
Catalogs
    id | catalog_slug
Brands
    id | brand_slug
Products
    id | product_slug | brand_id | catalog_id
```

How can I check if those parameters are related (by products table) and not that they just exist in the route? It works fine, but I want to make sure they are related each other.

Comment: How have you defined the relationships between the `Catalogs`, `Brands` and `Products` Models?

Comment: If the relation is defined, you should provide some more information and also controller method where the processing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your method:

```
$parameters = Route::current()->parameters();
$areRelated = DB::table('Products')
            ->join('Brands','Brands.id','=','Products.brand_id')
            ->join('Catalogs','Catalogs.id','=','Products.catalog_id')
            ->where('Catalogs.catalog_slug',$parameters['slug'])
            ->where('Brands.brand_slug',$parameters['brand'])
            ->where('Products.product_slug',$parameters['product'])
            ->count();
if(! areRelated )
    App::abort(404);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [route binding](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding).

```
Route::get('catalog/{catalog}/{brandByID}/{productByID}', 'Controller@method');
```

In bindings.php (create and include at end of globals.php)

```
Route::model('catalog', 'Catalog'); // now using {catalog} in route will look up the catalog instance by ID and pass it to the controller method instead of the ID.

// use custom resolver for brand parameter, use {brandByID} in route
Route::bind('brandByID', function ($brandID, $route) {
    //Get the catalog from the catalog bind function
    $catalog = $route->parameter('catalog');
    $brand = $catalog->brands()->findOrFail($brandID); // fails if catalog does not have this brand
    return $brand;
}
```

And do the same thing for the product but adding the second check. You also need the brands relation set correctly in your catalog model, e.g.

```
public function brands()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Brand');
}
```